# ASP.NET onselectedindexchanged event not firing when using loadcontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, user-controls

in a normal vb class i load a usercontrol with a dropdownlist

```
Dim products As UserControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Products.ascx")
                            products.ID = "Products"
                            tile.Controls.Add(products)
```

But my onindexchanged event (in the usercontrol) is not firing for some reason.

code:

```
Partial Class Controls_Products
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim myPage As BasePage = CType(Me.Page, BasePage)
        Dim dsProducts As DataSet = eyeCatalogueFunctions.GetProduct(0, myPage.GetLang, myPage.GetCustid, 0, "", 0, Nothing, 0)

        If Not IsNothing(dsProducts) AndAlso dsProducts.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso dsProducts.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With Me.ddlProducts
                .DataSource = dsProducts.Tables(0)
                .DataTextField = "product_nam"
                .DataValueField = "seqproduct"
                .DataBind()
            End With

            Me.lblTest.Text = Me.ddlProducts.Items(0).Text
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub ddlProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProducts.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Do something

End Sub
```

nothing special in the usercontrol :

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Products.ascx.vb" Inherits="Controls_Products" EnableViewState="true" %>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: It might help to post the code for the user control.

Comment: Will any event fire in the user control, say for instance you temporarily put a button in the user control and wired up a click event for it, does that work?

Comment: No that doesn't work either

Comment: Hmm, seems like the events are not being wired up correctly, could you post the markup for your user control?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the SelectedValueChanged event fires?

Comment: Are you re-loading that UserControl on every postback?

Comment: usercontrol is very basic, only dropdownlist see original post.
SelectedValuaChanged event doesn't fire
The usercontrol is re-loading on every postback, tried putting the dropdownlist in an update panel but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Check **AutoPostBack** property is set to **true** for the **products** control.

May be you can set it as **products.AutoPostBack=true**